# Can't find internal hard drive when installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I'm very new to Ubuntu and don't know much, so sorry if I'm doing something obviously wrong.

I'm having a lot of troubles trying to install Ubuntu on an old MacBook Air. I made a bootable USB drive using Etcher on another Mac, plugged it in and tried booting from it to install Ubuntu.

I got pretty far, but by some reason the installation failed. The computer shut down, and when I started it back up the screen was white with a flashing question mark on it.

I did some research, and by some reason, my internal hard drive seems to be gone. I can't find it in Disk Utility and I can't boot from it. Also, installing Ubuntu doesn't work, because it just tries installing it on the USB drive.

I actually got Ubuntu to work once. I just started the computer, and the Ubuntu loading screen showed up, and took me into Ubuntu. I thought it was finally working and started installing some programs. When pressing tab in the terminal, the screen froze. I restarted the computer, and Ubuntu was gone again.

---

EDIT: It happened again! The computer had turned off because of no energy left, and when I plugged a charger back in and started the computer, it started into Ubuntu. The same Ubuntu as last time, because my programs were still left.

Also, I tried to start the computer while holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, and the hard drive now showed up there, which means I could boot from it.

After about 2 minutes in Ubuntu, the screen froze, but not all at once. First, the current program froze, but I could still switch program and use the toolbars. After about 10 seconds, the whole screen was frozen, and I turned the computer off. When started it again, Ubuntu was gone.

Trying to get back into ubuntu by removing the charger and letting the computer discharge, but no luck.

I let the computer rest for a few minutes, and Ubuntu showed up again. So I plugged in my USB with Ubuntu on it and tried installing Ubuntu again. The installer now tried installing on the hard drive, not the USB, but froze before I could finish the installation. I quit the installer which started a live session. I tried opening the installer again, but it froze. I restarted the computer, and Ubuntu was gone.

Comment: You may want a lighter weight version like Lubuntu if old computer. Installed Lubuntu 18.04 LTS on a MacBook Air 1,1 (early 2008) 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402179

Comment: oldfred, that might work, but the main problem is that the installer can't find the hard drive. I'm going to try Lubuntu anyway

Comment: Do not know Mac, but many PC need UEFI update & many, even new, SSD need firmware update.

Comment: Tried installing Lubuntu, but now it tells me it can't create partition table

Comment: Are you booting in BIOS, not UEFI. You will want gpt partitioning not MBR (msdos) partitioning. And may be related to SSD firmware.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is a 2018 Mac, it likely has something to do with the T2 chip.

As I don't have the hardware available, let me direct you to the discussions that I've read.

- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/b511dv/macbook_from_2018_and_the_t2_chip/)
- [The T2 Security Chip is preventing Linux installs on New Macs even
  with Secure Boot set to
  off](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/9uh0lk/the_t2_security_chip_is_preventing_linux_installs/)

Comment: The Mac is from 2012, but I'll check out the links anyway :)

Comment: In that case, you might want to verify the hard disk works. Personally, I'd swap in an SSD with a computer of that vintage anyways.